# How to use Zebra TLP 2844 Printer with Laravel

Tags: laravel, printing, barcode, zebra-printers

I am creating barcode using Milon Laravel Package.
I have a **Zebra TLP 2844 Printer**, I want to send those barcode data to printer using Laravel.
All the Zebra printer solution asking for Port and IP, My printer only has usb port.

I have tried the following

- Already using Mike42/ECSPOS,Printer is not compatible.
  Here is the code

> ```
>         $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("ZDesigner-TLP-2844"); // Add connector for your printer here.
>         $printer = new Printer($connector);
>         $ticketim = imagecreatefrompng(public_path("img/barcode.png"));
>         $logo = new GdEscposImage();
>         $logo->readImageFromGdResource($ticketim);
> ```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your details are a bit thin.  How is the printer connected?  Is it attached to a USB port on the web server?  Is it attached to a USB port on a different machine and shared on the same local network as the web server?  Something else?

Comment: It is attached to the system using USB port, and project is on local environment, Not on any web server

Comment: The machine from which Laravel is serving your application (and on which the PHP code is running) is presumably acting as a web server (allows incoming HTTP requests, serves up web pages and responses)... The fact that this happens in a local environment is actually necessary for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Since you are using WindowsPrintConnector, I assume the machine running the PHP code and which the USB is plugged into is a Windows machine.  Did you share the printer on the network as recommended and verify with "The 'Hello World' receipt" test as described on GitHub?  https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php

Comment: I've share the printer on Network, The Name you see is coming from there.
And I've mentioned that it is not compatible with ECSPOS, I've done the testing but it is not sending print

Comment: Why voted down? Despite giving any solution